# How can I connect to Oracle Database without Oracle Client?

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, oracleclient

I want to connect to Oracle Database without Oracle Client. After searching that how can I do this, I figure out I must use Oracle Instant Client. But how can I use this? I cant find something about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended (and most frequently used) JDBC driver for Oracle is the ["thin driver"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html). It doesn't need anything installed on the client (and is free).

This FAQ might be useful : http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Answer (score 1):

For readers seeing the question but not the tags, Oracle has many "thin" drivers that don't need either the "Oracle Client" (such as installed by Oracle's GUI installer) or the "[Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html)" installed:

- [JDBC](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html)
- [.NET](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html)
- [Python](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/)
- [Node.js](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle client is a software that can easily be found and downloaded from oracle.com website. It has different versions for Windows, Linux, etc. After installing appropriate client, you will be able to communicate with the database by specifying its parameters such as host address, username, password etc. Without it, I think it's not possible to communicate with the  database server.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC
On this page it says: ***"You must use a JDBC OCI driver appropriate to your Oracle client installation."*** What I understand from here is that you should use JDBC driver in your application, but without client installed, it will be nonsense.